MS Access "JOIN expression not supported"
Why is my query not being accepted by Access?
SELECT
    NCR.Stage
    , AG.ID AS AgeGroup
    , Count(*) AS AgeGroupCount
FROM (
    qry1 AG
    LEFT JOIN qry1 AGi ON (
        AG.ID = AGi.ID + 1
    )
)
LEFT JOIN qry2 AS NCR ON (
    AG.AgeGroupLowerLimit <= NCR.Age
    AND (
        AGi.ID IS NULL
        OR AGi.AgeGroupLowerLimit > NCR.Age
    )
)
GROUP BY
    NCR.Stage
    , NCR.AgeGroup
;

The problem is related to the second left join, with qry2.

Could you give a full version of the error? It should tell you which line the error is happening in.

I'll have to look into how to do this. The error itself says nothing in particular, unless I need to inspect it in some special way I haven't configured.

I think, expression
(  AGi.ID IS NULL
        OR AGi.AgeGroupLowerLimit > NCR.Age
    )

you are referring to a field that is not available for reference in another table (part of the query).
You can try to move this condition to WHERE clause.
Try this
SELECT
    NCR.Stage
    , AG.ID AS AgeGroup
    , Count(*) AS AgeGroupCount
FROM (
    qry1 AG
    LEFT JOIN qry1 AGi ON AG.ID = (AGi.ID + 1)
)
LEFT JOIN qry2 AS NCR ON AG.AgeGroupLowerLimit <= NCR.Age
WHERE (
        AGi.ID IS NULL
        OR AGi.AgeGroupLowerLimit > NCR.Age
    )
GROUP BY
    NCR.Stage
    , NCR.AgeGroup
;

Also, in SELECT clause AG.ID AS AgeGroup - mast be part of GROUP BY.

Oh I think you may be exactly right. I didn't have time to work on this today, but I'll check tomorrow if I have time before the weekend. I think I've encountered this before after all, the conditions on the join are just too complex, maybe it can only take just one, I can't recall, in which case moving those to the WHERE would work. Thanks, I'll update you, or the post with more details, once I've tried this.
